# Kotlin + Spring issue with @Transient field with inheritance

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I have a situation in which I have a default "bank account" entity, and from it I can derive more specific types of bank accounts, hereby called FX. A FX entity can also be derived from to have even more specific bank accounts. To accomplish such, I made an interface, `DefaultBankAccount`, its implementation, `FXBankAccount`, and I can have classes that extends `FXBankAccount` to have country-specific bank accounts:

```
interface DefaultBankAccount {
    val accountNumber: String
    val address: String
    val bankName: String
    val codeIban: String
    val codeSwift: String
    val country: String
    val holderName: String
}

open class FxBankAccount(
    override var accountNumber: String,
    override var address: String,
    override var bankName: String,
    override var codeIban: String,
    override var codeSwift: String,
    override var country: String,
    override var holderName: String,
    var active: Boolean,
) : DefaultBankAccount

data class BrazilFxBankAccount(
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
    private val fxBankAccount: FxBankAccount,
    val bankCode: String,
    val branch: String,
    val digit: String,
    val type: String,
    val ispb: String,
    val docType: String,
    val docNumber: String
) : FxBankAccount(
    fxBankAccount.accountNumber,
    fxBankAccount.address,
    fxBankAccount.bankName,
    fxBankAccount.codeIban,
    fxBankAccount.codeSwift,
    fxBankAccount.country,
    fxBankAccount.holderName,
    fxBankAccount.active,
    fxBankAccount.paymentAgreement
)
```

The reason behind my BrazilFxBankAccount to have a `fxBankAccount` property in the constructor is:

1. If I simply override the fields in `BrazilFxBankAccount`, spring data will throw an error saying I have fields with the same name and need to annotate them with @Field to remove ambiguity, which will cause them to be persisted anyway with different names.
2. I tried using Delegation, but I can only Delegate interfaces, which FxBankAccount is not and cannot be, because it itself is implementing one

Everything works fine until persistance. Retrieving is the problem, because there is no `fxBankAccount` field saved in the database, and it is on the constructor, so mongoTemplate does not know how to build the object, throwing the following error:

```
No property `fxBankAccount` found on entity class BrazilFxBankAccount to bind constructor parameter to
```

And the error makes perfect sense. I understand why it is being thrown. I just don't know how to work around it. My current implementation is already a work-around to have three levels of abstraction. Any thoughts?

Comment: Would you be willing to consider composition instead of inheritance? I think you should still be able to get all the benefits you get from the abstraction.

Comment: Yes! Although I tried using composition and I had problems with that (it's been a while now and I can't quite remember what the problem was). I'll try your solution and give a feedback.

Comment: if this worked for you, would you consider accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your needs, but maybe [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) may help here as well.

It depends on how you would implement it, but you may have to do some or all of the following:

1. Persist the data in a somewhat different way (for example, instead of having the `DefaultBankAccount` saved on the persisted JSON, it could be nested inside an internal object).
2. Refactor some code usages (That nowadays accept `DefaultBankAccount` or `FxBankAccount`, or change the `BrazilFxBankAccount` to mimic the required behaviour).
3. Create and register custom `MongoCustomConversions`.